# (MATLAB) understand quadl vs quadv

Tags: matlab, math

Im trying to understand why a call like this

```
G = const * quadv(fun,a,b,tol)
```

returns different values than

```
lenB = length(b)
for  1 = 1:lenB
    G(i) = const .* quadl(fun,a,b,tol)
end
```

and how to achieve both calls to return the same values ?

**EDIT:**
I would like to run the quadl faster for arrays as well. So I would formulate the above question:

If it is possible, how to call quadl also for arrays (similar like the quadv call above), and thus increase performance by the calculations?

Comment: Even if I read the manual : "Use array operators .*, ./ and .^ in the definition of fun so that it can be evaluated with a vector argument." and "The quadv function vectorizes quad for an array-valued fun.", I couldnt retrieve the same results.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab's `quadl` uses adaptive Lobatto quadrature; `quadv` uses adaptive Simpson's rule.

The quality of the answer you get might depend on the function you assume.  What does your test `fun` look like?

I'll assume that you're passing the same function, limits, and tolerance to both calls.  That will mean the differences are smaller than the tolerance.

The two methods are different - Gaussian quadrature is not the same as Simpson's rule:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature

Comment: Thanks, apparently it is because of the underlying algorithm. I admit, I didnt pay attention to the (hidden) algorithm description of quadv, and I was just misled by the common leading "quad" of the two functions. So, now remains the question, how to make quadl working for vectors, otherwise it is pretty slow in terms of performance.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the help of [`quadl`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/quadl.html) and [`quadv`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/quadv.html), you see that `quadl` uses a different algorithm to integrate the function.

Numerical analysis almost never yields perfect results, so you cannot expect to get identical results.

Comment: Thanks, apparently it is because of the algorithm. Its not explicitly stated, that quadv is not using the same algorithm as the quadl. I just overread this hint in the function description.